# Is 1GB RAM so little?

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, memory, performance

I recently upgraded my old computer from Windows XP to Windows 7, and my computer became unbelievably slow. This is the hardware:

- Intel Pentium 4, 3.2 GHz
- 1GB RAM
- Radeon X800 GTO

By unbelievably slow I mean that if I open only one browser tab, and that has a Youtube video in it, the playback will stutter. If I play something in Media Player and open a browser, the playback will stutter. A friend recommended to put more RAM in it, and indeed, Win7 system requirements state that 1GB is the minimum.

Are the effects described normal?

Comment: If you mostly use this box to play Youtube videos, try using an application called Minitube (http://flavio.tordini.org/minitube), it plays YouTube videos directly without Flash or HTML5.  I had luck with it on a 900MHz Celeron with 1GB of RAM running Debian.  There is a Windows version.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Is 1GB RAM so little?

## Psychological Explanation

Like with most things computer, it depends on the usage.

> If I open only one browser tab, and that has a Youtube video in it, the playback will stutter. If I play something in Media Player and open a browser, the playback will stutter. A friend recommended to put more RAM in it, and indeed, Win7 system requirements state that 1GB is the minimum.

It sounds like the main issue here is a lingering, old-timey, outdated notion that web-browsing is a light-weight task that doesn’t require strong hardware. In the early days of the “web” (i.e., the mid-90’s), that was true and many people when buying a new system would sell their old one as a “web browsing system”. However, that was in the old days of simple, static HTML files. These days, web-browsing is indeed a power-hungry task because of all dynamic JavaScript, Silverlight, and especially Flash (which has *always* had extremely poor performance). The idea that old hardware can be used for browsing is simply no longer true; you do indeed need a (relatively) hefty machine to simply surf the web nowadays.

## Hardware Upgrade

> Intel Pentium 4, 3.2 GHz; 1GB RAM; Radeon X800 GTO

Those specs aren’t horrible (and they will certainly play many old games, including what used to be cutting-edge 3D shooters) just fine. However surprisingly enough, while it can play old 3D games with great performance, it may indeed struggle with just surfing “Web 2.0” sites (of which YouTube is certainly one), though simple, static sites should still be fine.

Obviously one solution is to add more RAM. Surprisingly, this can be a bit difficult because stores no longer sell older SDRAM and getting used hardware can be a chore because people often ask far too much for even old, slow, obsolete stuff (I blame shows like Antiques Roadshow for putting the idea that *all* old stuff is valuable in people’s minds).

## OS Optimization

As others have mentioned, Windows 7 is itself rather hardware-hungry and will gobble up (read waste) quite a bit of memory, especially with a default installation. If possible consider using XP or Linux or something lighter. If not, then you can lighten Windows 7 to make it less burdensome on the hardware.

To optimize your (or anyone else’s) old system for surfing or any other task, you should minimize Windows as much as possible. There are plenty of good guides that help you decide what to cut, but [Black Viper’s Windows Service list](http://www.blackviper.com/service-configurations/black-vipers-windows-7-service-pack-1-service-configurations/) is usually a good place to start. Turn off any and all unneeded Windows services, then use something like [Autoruns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb963902.aspx) to disable any and all unneeded programs from automatically running.

Once you have stripped Windows down to the basics, then you should have a lot more free memory (and CPU cycles for that matter) available for your designated task(s).

## Drivers for Performance

Of course you’ll also want to use the latest drivers for your hardware which may be a bit difficult to determine/find for anything that is discontinued like your X800 for which [Catalyst 10.2](http://support.amd.com/en-us/download/desktop/legacy?product=Legacy1&os=Windows%207%20-%2032) was the last driver released.

## Some Browsers are More Equal than Others

Another factor that affects web-surfing performance is the browser. For example, when the very first version of Chrome came out, it was blazingly and shockingly small, light, and fast. Over time, like most software, it became bloated and slow. Try different browsers to see which gives eh best performance on your system because they are definitely not all equal in this respect.

## Lightweight YouTube

Finally, in regards to YouTube in particular, try switching to the HTML5 player to see if it performs better than the Flash player as well as the [Feather version](https://www.youtube.com/testtube). Also try [YouTube Center](http://userscripts.org:8080/scripts/show/114002) to simplify and tweak YouTube.

Comment: (I have saved my old systems to “someday” play my old DOS games that I never had a chance to play yet.)

Comment: On XP and the same hardware YouTube and audio playback was just fine.

Answer (score 2):

Windows 7 32-bit will require a minimum of 1 GB Ram. It should work okay, but not spectacular.
Windows 7 64-bit will require a minimum of 2 GB Ram. So if you installed the 64 bit version, it will make things worse. Disabling Aero will speed things up a bit, but given that Windows 8.1 performs even better than Windows XP, My suggestion would be to either upgrade to windows 8.1 32 bit, or buy more ram.

I run Windows 8.1 32 bit on an old pc which has only an Intel Atom @1.6ghz with 1 GB ram, and it used to run Windows XP. Now, it runs so much better than when it ran XP. I can even watch 720p movies while I couldn't with Windows XP on it.

Comment: `but given that Windows 8.1 performs even better than Windows XP` Do you have a source for that? My recollection of that fact is that people's computers are now more well-built and can handle W8 better than XP

Comment: I have one source right now and that is my own experience. When my pc was still using XP, I was looking into upgrading it to windows 7 and I came across an article that stated the memory footprint and disksize usages of XP, 7, 8 and 8.1 where 8.1 was the smallest of all and for that reason works best on a system with little memory. That article made me decide to give windows 8.1 a try and its the best decision I made. Unfortunately, I can't find that article anymore.

Answer (score 1):

I aslo have recently installed Windows 7 into my Dell Demension 2400. It runs with 1.25 GB of RAM, and a Pentium 4 Processor. And for me, it runs smoothly, just every now and then it can get a bit laggy if I have more than two or three windows open. I would probably recommend that you upgrade your RAM to 4 GB+, that would probably be best, and fix your problem.

I would recommend (if you already havn't) going onto the task manager, and closing all of the unnecisary user processes. My usual CPU usage spikes all over the place even when nothing is open.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, 1GB ram is incredibly little. [Windows 7 alone requires ***at minimum*** 1GB ram](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/products/system-requirements) just to work. I would suggest at least upgrading it to 4GB if not 8.

Answer (score 0):

1 GB Ram is not a lot... and an upgrade will help your machine to perform better but P4 is 32 bits so it can only use up to 3GB RAM (so more than that is a waste of money in my opinion (maybe 4GB depending on the RAM sticks you can find for it).

Another option you could consider is to switch to linux with a lightweight window manager like lxde or xfce for example.